# I have integrated google plus in my IOS App ,But I am not able to get email Id of current user that is logged In

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, google-plus, google-plus-one

I have integrated google plus in my ios app ,I am able to sign in successfully but I am not able to get email Id of current user that is logged in.
I have referd to https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/ and have followed all the steps that are necessary for sign in!

So, How i get current User Mail ID that is Login  In Google plus?

[image]

Comment: Any ideas on how to integrate g+ hangout (video calling) in our ios application. I have gone through the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/sample-apps) of hangouts. But I see xml files as source code examples. How do I integrate it, is there a proficient tutorial...please help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

go to GTMOAuth2Authentication.m file
method setKeysForResponseDictionary in dic returns access token
at end of method.

```
accessTocken = [dict valueForKey:@"access_token"]; // access tocken pass in .pch file
[accessTocken retain];
```

and in your controller

```
- (IBAction)momentButton:(id)sender {
  NSString *str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=%@",accessTocken];
  NSString* escapedUrl = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",escapedUrl]];
  NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
  NSMutableDictionary *proDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

  proDic=[jsonData JSONValue];
  NSLog(@"%@",proDic);
```

Comment: hi Hardik thanks for your answer. I am able to get user email and id but i cant get user name. any idea ?

Comment: @Hardik Mamotra Any ideas on how to integrate g+ hangout (video calling) in our ios application. I have gone through the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/sample-apps) of hangouts. But I see xml files as source code examples. How do I integrate it, is there a proficient tutorial...please help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

This is the easiest and the simplest way of fetching the current logged in user's email id
first create an instance variable of GPPSignIn class

```
GPPSignIn *signIn;
```

then initialize it in the `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];

   static NSString * const kClientID = @"your client id";
   signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
   signIn.clientID= kClientID;
   signIn.scopes= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, nil];
   signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID=YES;
   signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail=YES;
   signIn.delegate=self;

   }
```

next implement the `GPPSignInDelegate` in your view controller
here you can get the logged in user's email id

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error:(NSError *)error
 {  
  NSLog(@"Received Access Token:%@",auth);
   NSLog(@"user google user id  %@",signIn.userEmail); //logged in user's email id
  }
```

Comment: It would be better to check error variable in finishedWithAuth.