# Using Google+ iOS API how to get logged in user's profile details?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I've managed to successfully log in to google plus from an iPhone app. But how to get logged in user's details? such as profile id, email etc.

I tried this,
[Stackoverflow answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302904/i-have-integrated-google-plus-in-my-ios-app-but-i-am-not-able-to-get-email-id-o) but I was unable to get it working. In that sample what exactly is being passed to accessTocken here,

```
NSString *str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=%@",accessTocken];
```

I've implemented that code in `- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error
{ }` method. however `auth.accessToken` returns a null value.

so I can not use auth.accessToken to append that URL. Is there any other way to get this done?

Answer (score 34):

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Received Error %@ and auth object==%@", error, auth);

    if (error) {
        // Do some error handling here.
    } else {
        [self refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn];

        GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

        NSLog(@"email %@ ", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email: %@",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail]);
        NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);

        // 1. Create a |GTLServicePlus| instance to send a request to Google+.
        GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
        plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

        // 2. Set a valid |GTMOAuth2Authentication| object as the authorizer.
        [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];

        // 3. Use the "v1" version of the Google+ API.*
        plusService.apiVersion = @"v1";
        [plusService executeQuery:query
                completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                    GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                    NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                //Handle Error
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Email= %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail);
                NSLog(@"GoogleID=%@", person.identifier);
                NSLog(@"User Name=%@", [person.name.givenName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", person.name.familyName]);
                NSLog(@"Gender=%@", person.gender);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Hope, this will help you

Comment: Above is right solution for get user profile info, Now I want to get my friend list that is also possible from below link:  https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people                         But I am not able to get emails of my friend list, I think there is some scope issue. Any Help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If email is nil use this : GTLPlusPersonEmailsItem *personEmailsItem = [person.emails objectAtIndex:0];NSLog(@"Email=%@", personEmailsItem.value);

Answer (score 14):

This is the easiest and the simplest way of fetching the current logged in user's email id
first create an instance variable of GPPSignIn class

```
GPPSignIn *signIn;
```

then initialize it in the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];

  static NSString * const kClientID = @"your client id";
  signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
  signIn.clientID= kClientID;
  signIn.scopes= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, nil];
  signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID=YES;
  signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail=YES;
  signIn.delegate=self;

 }
```

next implement the `GPPSignInDelegate` in your view controller
 here you can get the logged in user's email id

```
 - (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
           error:(NSError *)error
 {  
  NSLog(@"Received Access Token:%@",auth);
  NSLog(@"user google user id  %@",signIn.userEmail); //logged in user's email id
 }
```

Comment: Nice :) much better the @Avi answer

Answer (score 1):

First, follow [this instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) to setup your project in [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com) (and to download configuration file GoogleService-Info.plist) and to integrate the latest [GoogleSignIn SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/)
into your project: [Integration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

*A piece of code.*

Here is the code for getting user info with the latest version of [GoogleSignIn SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/) at this moment.

```
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
//...

@interface ViewController() <GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate>
//...

- (IBAction)googleSignInTapped:(id)sender {
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientId;// Replace with the value of CLIENT_ID key in GoogleService-Info.plist
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES; //Setting the flag will add "email" and "profile" to scopes. 

    NSArray *additionalScopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
                                  @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
                                  @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"];

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:additionalScopes];

    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
}

#pragma mark - GoogleSignIn delegates
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        //TODO: handle error
    } else {
        NSString *userId   = user.userID;
        NSString *fullName = user.profile.name;
        NSString *email    = user.profile.email;
        NSURL *imageURL    = [user.profile imageURLWithDimension:1024];
        NSString *accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken; //Use this access token in Google+ API calls.

        //TODO: do your stuff 
    }
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Your *AppDelegate.m*

```
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
//...
@implementation AppDelegate

//...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //...
    return YES;
}

//For iOS 9.0 and later
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options {
    //...
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}

//For your app to run on iOS 8 and older, 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(nonnull id)annotation {
    //...
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                      annotation:annotation];
}

@end
```

Also make sure that you've added URL Scheme with your **REVERSED_CLIENT_ID** which you can find in GoogleService-Info.plist.

---

To be able to get list of your connections in Google+ you need to enable `Google People API` and `Google+ API` for your project in [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Then just send HTTP request to the following url: 
**https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN**

---

To check if user has a Google+ profile just send HTTP request to the following url: 
**https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/USER_ID?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN**
and check the value of `"isPlusUser"` which will be `"true"` or `"false"`

[image]

*Little bonus*
[EXAMPLE PROJECT](https://github.com/arturdev/Google-demo)

Comment: sounds you didn't read the bounty details above ... read it please

Comment: @JAHelia What part I've missed?

Comment: how can I determine if the logged in user has a google plus profile, and if any, get their profile details, how to do that ?

Comment: @JAHelia I've already show how to get profile details, but about google plus profile I'm not sure, is it even possible to login with google without having google plus account?

Comment: yes a user may have a google account but does not have a google plus account, I don't know how to know that with the Google Sign In api

Comment: @JAHelia But why you need to know that? What is your purpose?

Comment: to provide a google plus sign in in my app, but i've shocked when I found out that google has deprecated google+ sign in, so I have to use google sign in then get the logged in user's google+ profile details (profile image, profile public link, circles, etc ..)

Comment: @JAHelia Got it. See edited answer,, I've also made example project, just run it on simulator.

Comment: Ok cool thank you, is it possible to know whether the logged in user has a google plus profile or not ?

Comment: you deserve the bounty, thank you so much for your answer. however by the way I have another open issue regarding login on Instagram and I will open a bounty if I couldn't get an answer, here is the question if you got some time for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898044/instagram-api-prevents-redirection-to-ios-app-upon-successful-login