# I have integrated google plus in my IOS App , Now how can i get profile detail of logged in user?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus

I have integrated google plus in my ios app ,I am able to get access token.I have used authentication flow to integrate google plus.So now after getting access token how can i get user profile details like username, email id, profile pic etc?
My code to get access token is as below:

```
-(IBAction)btnGooglePlusClicked:(UIButton *)sender
```

{
    IBwebView.hidden = FALSE;

```
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&data-requestvisibleactions=%@",GOOGLE_PLUS_CLIENT_ID,GOOGLE_PLUS_CALL_BACK_URL,GOOGLE_PLUS_SCOPE,GOOGLE_PLUS_VISIBLE_ACTIONS];


[IBwebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

}
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //    [indicator startAnimating];
    if ([[[request URL] host] isEqualToString:@"localhost"]) {

```
    // Extract oauth_verifier from URL query
    NSString* verifier = nil;
    NSArray* urlParams = [[[request URL] query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    for (NSString* param in urlParams) {
        NSArray* keyValue = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString* key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"code"]) {
            verifier = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];
            NSLog(@"verifier %@",verifier);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (verifier) {
        NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&redirect_uri=%@&grant_type=authorization_code", verifier,GOOGLE_PLUS_CLIENT_ID,GOOGLE_PLUS_CLIENT_SECRET,GOOGLE_PLUS_CALL_BACK_URL];
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    } else {
        // ERROR!
    }

    [webView removeFromSuperview];

    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"verifier %@",receivedData);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *jResponse = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *tokenData = [jResponse objectWithString:response];
    //  WebServiceSocket *dconnection = [[WebServiceSocket alloc] init];
    //   dconnection.delegate = self;

    NSString *pdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=3&token=%@&secret=123&login=%@", [tokenData objectForKey:@"refresh_token"], self.isLogin];
    //  NSString *pdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=3&token=%@&secret=123&login=%@",[tokenData accessToken.secret,self.isLogin];
    //  [dconnection fetch:1 withPostdata:pdata withGetData:@"" isSilent:NO];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Google Access TOken"
                              message:pdata
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: check from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17425708/3755954

Comment: @cyberlobe please check my question again. Your link has answer using GTLServicePlus . I want outh flow to implement this in my code.

Comment: kindly check below solution on same page see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15963678/3755954

Comment: @cyberlobe its using GPPSignIn. I want solution using outh . This is not there. I have already checked this links.

Comment: i appreciate your effort, Please check link in my answer may be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the the method you are using will not help to get the profile detail.

I suggest to use the proper method which ensures the best results.

Please check this out : https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/

This will surely help you to get required outcome.